# Error importing from Excel to Access with ADO

Tags: excel, ms-access, ado

I am trying to export data from a excel file to an access file using vba.

My code is

```
Sub Export_Data()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim nextrow As Long

'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:

'Variables for file path and last row of data
dbPath = Sheet19.Range("I3").Value
nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Initialise the collection class variable
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'Check for data
If Sheet18.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
MsgBox " Add the data that you want to send to MS Access"
Exit Sub
End If

'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
'—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
'two primary providers used in ADO SQLOLEDB —-Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 —-Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
'OLE stands for Object Linking and Embedding, Database

'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
rst.Open Source:="ARF Form Log", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable

'you now have the recordset object
'add the values to it
For x = 2 To nextrow
rst.AddNew
For i = 1 To 29
rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
Next i
rst.Update
Next x

'close the recordset
rst.Close
' Close the connection
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'communicate with the user
MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"

'Update the sheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'show the next ID
Sheet19.Range("h7").Value = Sheet19.Range("h8").Value + 1

'Clear the data
Sheet18.Range("A2:ac1000").ClearContents
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:

'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
End Sub}
```

Where:

Sheet 19 contains my path to the access file

Sheet 18 contains the data I want to transfer

When I try to transfer my data from sheet 18 into the access table i receive the error:

Error -2147217900 (Syntax error in From clause.) in procedure Export_Data

I have checked that my headings match between the access file and the excel file and the Data type format is the same.

I am unsure where there is an issue.

Let me know your thoughts, thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adCmdOpenTable` still requires your table name to be bracketed. In essence, it just appends `SELECT * FROM` at the start of your source, and then tries to execute it. Because your table name has spaces, that leads to a syntax error in the `From` clause.

Either add brackets or use a normal query instead:

```
rst.Open Source:="SELECT * FROM [ARF Form Log]", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: Now it is uploading to the Access file but the table remains blank after the export. Is there an issue with this code                                                                                          {'add the values to it
For x = 2 To nextrow
rst.AddNew
For i = 1 To 29
rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
Next i
rst.Update
Next x

'close the recordset
rst.Close
' Close the connection
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing}